# Scroll to top on the listview : How to get listview from my adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

[UPDATE]

Here is the code of AlsaceFragment class :

```
public class AlsaceNewsFragment extends ListFragment implements PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    private RssServiceAlsace rssService;
    private static final String URL_LALSACE = "http://www.lalsace.fr/actualite/alsace/rss";

    private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AlsaceNewsFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        refreshList(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }

        // CACHER SEPARATEURS
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        boolean enleverseparateur = settings.getBoolean("enleverseparateur", false);
        if (enleverseparateur == true){
            getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
            getListView().setDivider(null);
        }
        // FIN CACHER SEPARATEURS

        ListView listView = getListView();
        mPullToRefreshAttacher = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPullToRefreshAttacher();
        mPullToRefreshAttacher.setRefreshableView(listView, this);

    }

    public void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Called when pullToRefresh has been started
     */
    public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
        refreshList(false); // We don't want to show progress dialog in this case
    }

    private void refreshList(boolean displayLoading){
        rssService = new RssServiceAlsace(this, displayLoading);

        // UNE SOURCE
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        boolean unesource = settings.getBoolean("unesource", false);    
        if (unesource == true) {
            rssService.execute(URL_LALSACE);
        } else {
            rssService.execute(URL_LALSACE);
        }
        // FIN UNE SOURCE

    }

    public void notifyPullFinished() {
        // Notify PullToRefreshAttacher that the refresh has finished
        mPullToRefreshAttacher.setRefreshComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ArticleAlsace article = (ArticleAlsace) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("URL", article.getUrl());
        arguments.putString("TITRE", article.getTitle());
        arguments.putString("SOURCE", article.getSource());
        arguments.putString("DESCRIPTION", article.getDescription());
        Fragment fragment = new WebBrowserFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
    }
}
```

I try to implement a new menu item in my Action Bar which will be visible when the user start the scroll in the listView of my app.

I would like to bind the click of the button with a method which will be responsible to scroll to the top of the listview.

To do this, i would like to use :

```
getListView().setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Here is a piece of code of My main activity :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_arrow_top :

                    // I would like to scroll to the top of my list here, but in this class (MainActivity) i don't have access to the list .. :( 
            AlsaceNewsFragment.goToTop();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And here is the code of goToTop method in AlsaceNewFragment (which extends ListFragment) :

```
public static void goToTop() {
        getListView().setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
    }
```

But i get this error :

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getListView() from the type ListFragment
```

Maybe there is a better simple way to do what i want.

My app is composed on :

- MainActivity which extends Activity
- One ListFragment which create the list
- An AlsaceAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Read about the `static` keyword: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `static` keyword from goToTop() method. Static methods can't access instance data.

Comment: When i remove static keywork, i got an error in my MainActivity class : `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method goToTop() from the type AlsaceNewsFragment`

Comment: Do you have access to part of the code for  AlsaceNewsFragment class? Maybe you could get rid of all those static keywords and the problem could dissapear.

Comment: I have added the code in my post. Could you have a look please ?